# SELECT query inside case in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, case

I have an update query and inside it, I want to update column1 based on the number of rows it has.

I have tried the following, but it doesnt seem to be working. It just adds them all on `NULL`.

```
UPDATE table AS t1 SET

t1.column1 = (CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt FROM table t2 WHERE t2.column1 IS NULL AND t2.uq_id = t1.uq_id) < 10 THEN NULL
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt FROM table t2 WHERE t2.column1 = 2 AND t2.uq_id = t1.uq_id) < 10 THEN 2
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt FROM table t2 WHERE t2.column1 = 3 AND t2.uq_id = t1.uq_id) < 10 THEN 3
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt FROM table t2 WHERE t2.column1 = 4 AND t2.uq_id = t1.uq_id) < 10 THEN 4
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt FROM table t2 WHERE t2.column1 = 5 AND t2.uq_id = t1.uq_id) < 10 THEN 5
    ELSE t1.column1
END)

WHERE t1.num IN (xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4) AND t1.uq_id = xxx;
```

**Edit:**

eg:
Considering that when 
`column1 = NULL` it has `9` rows, 
`column1 = 1` has `9` rows, 
`column1 = 2` has `7` rows.

The expected result should be;

- When num = xx1 column1 = NULL
- When num = xx2 column1 = 1
- When num = xx3 column1 = 2
- When num = xx4 column1 = 2

The actual result is;

- When num = xx1 column1 = NULL
- When num = xx2 column1 = NULL
- When num = xx3 column1 = NULL
- When num = xx3 column1 = NULL

**Edit 2:**

I also tried the following to remove all those `WHEN`s

```
t1.column1 = (SELECT column1
    FROM table
    WHERE (
        SELECT column1
        FROM table t2
        WHERE t2.uq_id = t1.uq_id
        GROUP BY column1
        HAVING COUNT(*) < 10
        ORDER BY column1 ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) p
)
```

The issue to my understanding, is that when the first `num` gets updated, the count of the rows doesn't (?) and therefore when the column1 = NULL it still has 9 rows count, till the end of this update.

**Edit 3:**
The issue was probably the fact that I used the above query in a transactions thus disabling auto-commit.

Comment: Please show us the full query, and sample data would also be nice.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, please give me some time.

Comment: What version of my-sql driver are in place? Also, what is the default value of autocommit? Since MySQL does default commit on each DML statement, is it somehow disabled?

Comment: @Rizwan It is not. Though that query among with some others are inside a transaction, I dont know if that plays any role.

Comment: Ooops.. _With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts to its previous state._ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html So is there any way to have that in a transaction to be safe in case anything happens to rollback and have auto-commit on (perhaps contradicting) ?

Comment: @JohnJames yes Could you upvote the comment if that helped to find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Would this satisfy your requirements?

```
UPDATE `table` AS t1 LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t2.uq_id, t2.column1 
    FROM `table` t2 WHERE t2.column1 IN (NULL,2,3,4,5)
   GROUP BY t2.column1 HAVING COUNT(*)<10
 ) _t2 ON _t2.uq_id=t1.uq_id
SET t1.column1 = _t2.column1
WHERE t1.num IN (xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4) AND t1.uq_id = xxx
;
```

Comment: The group by is wrong, among other things. You are grouping by the unique id number.

Comment: i adjusted the `GROUP BY` to be on the column1. in your example, I assumed it was non-unique since your aggregation of COUNT(*) in your subquery would only ever return 1 record (i.e. always < 10) since you have it combined w/ the conditional of `AND t2.uq_id = t1.uq_id` ..which, now that i think about it, is probably why they were all NULLs as you had claimed to begin with.

Comment: Nope still doesnt work. I think the issue is what I pointed out at my last edit.